# Default Word Web Add-In Starter Template does not build in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: node.js, ms-word, office365, ms-office, office-addins

I have created a new **Word Web Add-In** in Visual Studio 2019. Whenever I try to run it, I get the following errors:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: WordWebAddIn1Web, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>C:\Users\Me\node_modules\@types\fs-extra\index.d.ts(188,87): error TS2694: Build:Namespace '"fs"' has no exported member 'Dir'.
1>C:\Users\Me\node_modules\@types\fs-extra\index.d.ts(191,17): error TS2694: Build:Namespace '"fs"' has no exported member 'OpenDirOptions'.
1>C:\Users\Me\node_modules\@types\fs-extra\index.d.ts(192,53): error TS2694: Build:Namespace '"fs"' has no exported member 'Dir'.
1>C:\Users\Me\node_modules\@types\fs-extra\index.d.ts(194,52): error TS2694: Build:Namespace '"fs"' has no exported member 'OpenDirOptions'.
1>C:\Users\Me\node_modules\@types\fs-extra\index.d.ts(194,80): error TS2694: Build:Namespace '"fs"' has no exported member 'Dir'.
1>C:\Users\Me\node_modules\@types\fs-extra\index.d.ts(265,52): error TS2694: Build:Namespace 'NodeJS' has no exported member 'ArrayBufferView'.
1>C:\Users\Me\node_modules\@types\fs-extra\index.d.ts(265,167): error TS2694: Build:Namespace 'NodeJS' has no exported member 'ArrayBufferView'.
1>C:\Users\Me\node_modules\@types\fs-extra\index.d.ts(266,52): error TS2694: Build:Namespace 'NodeJS' has no exported member 'ArrayBufferView'.
1>C:\Users\Me\node_modules\@types\fs-extra\index.d.ts(266,149): error TS2694: Build:Namespace 'NodeJS' has no exported member 'ArrayBufferView'.
1>C:\Users\Me\node_modules\@types\fs-extra\index.d.ts(267,52): error TS2694: Build:Namespace 'NodeJS' has no exported member 'ArrayBufferView'.
2>------ Build started: Project: WordWebAddIn1, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>  Successfully created package at: C:\Users\Me\Development\C#\Office Web Addin\WordWebAddIn1\bin\Debug\WordWebAddIn1.debugapp
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I have already deleted the fs-extra folder from node_modules and installed `npm install -g @types\fs-extra`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer, I had to delete the `@types\fs-extra` folder from my global node_modules.