# Problem with exported members 'StatSyncFn'

Tags: angular, webpack, angular13

There is this error on my build, i dont no from where and why, is coming like this...

```
Error: node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware/types/index.d.ts:204:27 - error TS2694: Namespace '"fs"' has no exported member 'StatSyncFn'.

 statSync?: import("fs").StatSyncFn;
```

I have try to re-install webpack, but and don't know what, i will doing for resume this error...

Having some solutions or ideas for ? Please,

Thank all us for you help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check [this](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/44946) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62697011/default-word-web-add-in-starter-template-does-not-build-in-visual-studio-2019).

There are 2 possible reasons:

1. Haven't updated node to latest `(npm@7.5.4 => fs-extra@8.0.1)` version
2. Messed-up with destination locations.

**most probably updating npm and fs-extra would solve

Comment: Nothing to change and i have two errors more...Error: node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-webpack/src/webpack-dev-server/index.d.ts:26:121 - error TS2307: C
annot find module '../../../core/src' or its corresponding type declarations.

26 declare const _default: import("@angular-devkit/architect/src/internal").Builder<WebpackDevServerBuilderSchema & import("../../../core/src").JsonObj
ect>;

Comment: Error: node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-webpack/src/webpack/index.d.ts:30:116 - error TS2307: Cannot find 
module '../../../core/src' or its corresponding type declarations.

30 declare const _default: import("@angular-devkit/architect/src/internal").Builder<RealWebpackBuilderSchema & import("../../../core/src").JsonObject>;